# How to insert into postgres jsonb column using pyspark?

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to insert the value of a column (`stores`) into a postgres jsonb column. I'm reading this data from a csv file and it is like below when I read it:

```
+------------------------------------+
|stores                              |
+------------------------------------+
|[28, 29, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]|
|[28, 29, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]|
+------------------------------------+
```

The schema is like this:

```
root
 |-- stores: string (nullable = true)
```

Inserting this column into a postgres jsonb column has below error:

> ERROR: column "stores" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
> Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

So I tried to change the column to json like this:

```
.withColumn("stores", to_json(split(regexp_replace(col("stores"), '\\[|\\]', ''), ",")))
```

Also I tried this which has error:

```
.withColumn("stores", to_json(col("stores")))
```

> cannot resolve 'to_json(stores)' due to data type mismatch: Input type string must be a > > struct, array of structs or a map or array of map

Then tried to change the schema and use `ArrayType` which faced the error that it is not supported by csv.

This is the reading and inserting code.

```
df = spark.read \
        .option("header", True) \
        .format("csv") \
        .load(path) \
        .withColumn("stores", to_json(split(regexp_replace(col("stores"), '\\[|\\]', ''), ",")))
        
        
df.select(col("stores")) \
        .write \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", db_url) \
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
        .option("dbtable", target_table) \
        .option("user", db_user) \
        .option("password", db_password) \
        .mode("append") \
        .save()
```

How should I do that?